# Count number of ongoing conversations in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

How to calculate the number of distinct conversations in the table?

table:

| Caller | Receiver |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | D |
| C | A |
| A | C |
| C | B |
| D | B |
| B | A |
| B | D |

in the table above, the conversations are between
A:B, A:C, B:C, B:D.

Therefore, the expected result is 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `LEAST` and `GREATEST` functions here:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(Caller, Receiver),
                    GREATEST(Caller, Receiver)
    FROM yourTable
) t;
```

In the above logic `A -> B` and `B -> A` would both be treated as `A -> B`, and would be counted only once.